# Как экранировать слеши json при записи в базу

Tags: php, json

Как экранировать спец символы json точнее слеши?

Проблема в тот что пропадают слеши при записи в базу mysql

это \u041c\u043e\u0439 \u041c\u0430\u0433\u0430\u0437\u0438\u043d"

превращается в базе в это

u041cu043eu0439 u041cu0430u0433u0430u0437u0438u043d

Comment: а как записываешь? покажи код

Comment: кажется уже догадался, нужны вместо одного \  записывать в sql запросе двойной \\  и тогда запишется

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать [addslashes ( string )](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.addslashes.php)

```html
<?php
$str_json = json_encode ("какая-то строка"); //JSON-представление данных
$str = AddSlashes ($str_json); //Экранирует строку с помощью слешей
/* ... вставляем в запрос MySQL ... */
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Помогает str_replace('\\', '\\\\',  $json);

```
 $description = "Мой Магазин";

$hometext = json_encode($description);


$hometext = str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $hometext);

echo $hometext;


query("INSERT into TABLE $hometext(`id`, `json`) VALUES (NULL, '$hometext')";);
```

Comment: лучше все же напишите, как и что вы записываете, ибо как то все это весьма странно выглядит.

Comment: написал))) теперь всем станет понятно)

Comment: Используйте подготовленные запросы и биндинг параметров, тогда подобные вопросы возникать не будут в принципе. и вообще вы уверены, что имя таблицы в виде json-кодированной строки это нормально? (:

Comment: это я для примера написал))))))))) у меня имена таблиц совсем другие

Answer (score 0):

При формировании sql-запроса экранировать надо не только слэши. Кавычки, апострофы и другие используемые в sql символы могут не только сломать вам запрос, но и привести к серьёзным проблемам с безопасностью (почитайте про [sql-инъекции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)).

Разработчики библиотек для работы с базами данных обычно предоставляют функции экранирования. Например, в PDO есть есть функция [quote](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.quote.php), в mysqli -- [real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). Используйте их.

Обратите внимание, что для вашего удобства существуют интерфейсы, позволяющие испрользовать [подготовленные запросы](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php) (или экранировать параметры автоматически). Например в PDO вы можете написать запрос подставив на место данных *плэйсхолдеры* (специальные метки, которые потом меняются на значения), и затем исполнить такой запрос передав в него данные (смотрите документацию и примеры к [PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php)). Попробуйте, это очень удобно!